# Runtime Error '424' Object Required

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

I have a range of data in cells `BA8` through and including `BN10` in worksheet `"HR Eval Report"` in the active workbook.

I want to **sort this range** in ascending order based upon the values in cells `BC8:BC10`. Here is the part of my code causing problems:

```
Dim rngOutData As Range
...
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("HR Eval Report").Range("BA8").Select
Set rngOutData = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("HR Eval Report").Range(Selection, _
Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
```

The `Set rngOutData` statement throws the error. I have tried fully qualifying the range as similar `424` problem answers indicated that as a solution, but it didn't solve the problem. Any advice greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare your objects and work with it. Avoid the use of selection. You may want to see [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)

Here is a simple way to sort your range ascending on `BC8`

```
Dim rngOutData As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("HR Eval Report")

Set rngOutData = ws.Range("BA8:BN10")

With rngOutData
    .Sort Key1:=ws.Range("BC8"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, _
    OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
    DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
End With
```

**Note**: If your data doesn't have headers then change `Header:=xlYes` to `Header:=xlNo` as suggested correctly by @Jeeped in the comments below.

Comment: With only three rows to sort, do you think there is a header? The OP may need `, Header:=xlNo` . `Key1:=ws.Range("BA8")` might have to be `Key1:=.Columns(3)` .

Comment: @Jeeped: I don't know the answer to that question as OP as not mentioned anything :) However, it is a good point. I will mention that in the above post.

Comment: @Jeeped: Mentioned that in the post. Regarding your recent edit regarding the key, what I mentioned is correct.

Comment: I thought the OP had stated *'ascending order based upon the values in cells BC8:BC10'*.

Comment: @Jeeped: Ah I see what you mean. I misread it. in that case wouldn't `Key1:=ws.Range("BC8")` suffice?

Comment: Sure, I was just using the method that I generally use when coding a `.Cells.Sort` within a With/End With (third column). Sorry for being obtuse.

Comment: @Jeeped: No you are not being obtuse :) You picked up an obvious thing that I missed. I thank you for bringing that to my notice.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code is throwing an error is that you are trying to assign the *return value* of `Range.Select` to an object variable.  However, the `Select` method doesn't return an object, it returns `True` (if the range was successfully selected).

There are two ways to achieve exactly what your code is trying to do: select the range and then assign the selection to the object variable:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("HR Eval Report").Range("BA8").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("HR Eval Report").Range(Selection, _
    Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Set rngOutData = Selection
```

or assign the range to the variable and then select that:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("HR Eval Report").Range("BA8").Select
Set rngOutData = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("HR Eval Report").Range(Selection, _
    Selection.End(xlToRight))
rngOutData.Select
```

However almost certainly there are much better ways to achieve the overall objective of sorting the cells, and you should generally avoid the use of `Select` ([see this question for more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros?lq=1)).  To get the same range into `rngOutData` for instance, the following is faster, more robust and easier to read:

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("HR Eval Report")
    Set rngOutData = .Range(.Range("BA8"), .Range("BA8").End(xlToRight))
End With
```

A similar thing applies to `ActiveWorkbook` - generally it would be better to have a variable containing a reference to the workbook and use that.

Comment: Thank you, Aucuparia, your first method solved another problem I was having.  All you folks are great!

Answer (score -1):

Try with this one, just follow the ' IF YOU... Step

```
Sub order()

Sheets("HR Eval Report").Select
Range("BC8").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("HR Eval Report").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("HR Eval Report").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("BC8"), _
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("HR Eval Report").Sort
    .SetRange Range("BA8:BN10")
    .Header = xlNo ' IF YOU HAVE TITLE ON THE COLUMN THEN SET .Header x1Yes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

End Sub

Comment: I have just the right link for you :) Check the 3rd sentence in my post ;)

Comment: Thank you, Luis, your code worked wonderfully and with no need to use Set.